# Open I PDF in a new window and print in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, vuejs3, microsoft-edge

I am using Vue3.js. I need to open a PDF in a new window, then open the print dialog but this only works on MS Edge and Google Chrome, but does not work on Firefox or Safari.

```js
    const getBlobPdf = async (url: string) => {
      const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: "blob" });
      return new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
    };

    const printPdf = async ({ url }) => {
      const blob = await getBlobPdf(url);
      window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), "_blank")?.print();
    };
```

I had tried `window.focus(); window.print();` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work on Firefox and Safari. But I don't know if there is another way without using `setTimeout()`

```ts
const printPdf = async ({ url }) => {
      const blob = await getBlobPdf(url);
      const printWin = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), "_blank");
      if (printWin) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          printWin.print();
        }, 200);
      }
    };
```